# Сохранить файл с текущей датой SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть ли возможность в Oracle сохранить файл с текущей датой?
То есть необходимо создать две переменные типа `а= 'file_' b= sysdate`
и необходимо сохранить `a||b` и получить `file_01.02.2022` например

Comment: где вам необходимо создать файл - на Oracle сервере или локально? ЕМНИП, Oracle не умеет работать с файлами локально (на стороне клиента)

Comment: Работаю в SAS , файл на сервер сохраняется